# Sentence with でできる

Tags: grammar, syntax

According to Tobira textbook (Lesson 1, grammar point 1), {で / から} できる is used to express "to be made from" when generic statements, while {で / から} できている is used to express "to be made from" when describing something specific.

Could you please show me some examples with "でできる" (NOT でできている)?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The major difference between the ている form and the normal form is that the former is more about the state of being made, whereas the latter is more about the action of being made.

Maybe understanding it as it is translated below could help you:

> 紙でできる箱です。: It is a box that we make with paper.
>
> 紙でできている箱です。: It is a box made with paper.

Other examples with でできる:

> ご飯でできるちょっと変わったアイデアレシピ。
>
> 余ったご飯でできる煎餅の作り方を紹介している。
>
> うまいアイスコーヒーは水でできる！

You also see this form a lot in its past tense form.

Comment: so... the ている form focuses on the object, while the できる form puts the focus more on the "actor", the person who has caused the object to be made?

Comment: I think the problem that I have with this is that I don't mentally translate any of these forms of でできる into, as Rick asked about, the phrase "to be made from" when generic statements" Each of your examples, translates more naturally into "An X that you **can make** from Y" statements.  At least, that is how I parse them.

Comment: Seeing your examples, I would also translate でできる as "can be made", but then, should I reject the "to be made from" translation, or are there cases in which でできる means "to be made from" in generic statements (for example: X は Y でできる) ?

Comment: @ericfromabeno You are right, that's how I see it too. However when used in the past tense, as in sentences like 紙でできた箱, I wouldn't really understand it as "_box that I could make with paper_" but more like "_box that was made with paper_" (more like でできている). So I think there isn't one universal translation for the word. But maybe taking a look at the kanji can help you understand better the meaning whatever form it's used in: 出/来る = "come/out"  with the meaning of 現れる, 完成

Comment: 紙でできる箱 = box that "comes out" using paper, 紙でできている箱 = box that "has come out" using paper, 紙でできた箱 = box that "came out" with paper

Answer (score 0):

that's interesting... I don't think I've ever seen "でできる" used in that manner. Where I normally see "でできる" is in describing how a thing can be done, or the amount of time a thing can be done in:

> 30日でできる
>   5分でできる
>   スマホでできる仕事
>   自宅でできる仕事
>   一人でできる仕事
>   フライパン一つでできるレシピ

looking forward to a native Japanese answer to this question.